# How to change urls in <a> to seo in Opencart 2.x automatically?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo, opencart2.x

I'm using Opencart 2.x version and shop installed in /shop subdirectory.
I know how to enable seo_url (.htaccess.txt -> .htaccess, set RewriteBase to /shop/ and enable SEO urls in admin panel).

Seo urls works and my links like `information/information_id=1` changed to `/faq` etc.

Problem is that if I add in url_alias table records: `inforamtion/contact = contact` - this url works, but on the site it still looks like `/shop/index.php?route=information/contact` not as `/shop/contact`

I supposed that it should be changed automatically, but not. All site's links for product, categories and information pages had been changed, but that added by me manually - NOT. Why?

PS: I can change it in code, but think it is not good solution cos suppose exists correct way to do what I need.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure if you have already got an answer to your question, but I'll leave it here anyway, since it took me a couple days to figure this one out.

In order to change from `/index.php?route=information/contact` to just `/contact`, you require two steps

(You probably got step 1 ready already)

1. Perform the following inserts in your OC database. This covers all (As for 2.1.0.1, at least) the system pages that allow now SEO settings. You can change the keywords to whatever you feel more suited.

```html
INSERT INTO url_alias (query, keyword) VALUES ('common/home', '');
INSERT INTO url_alias (query, keyword) VALUES ('account/wishlist', 'wishlist');
INSERT INTO url_alias (query, keyword) VALUES ('account/account', 'my-account');
INSERT INTO url_alias (query, keyword) VALUES ('checkout/cart', 'shopping-cart');
INSERT INTO url_alias (query, keyword) VALUES ('checkout/checkout', 'checkout');
INSERT INTO url_alias (query, keyword) VALUES ('account/login', 'login');
INSERT INTO url_alias (query, keyword) VALUES ('account/logout', 'logout');
INSERT INTO url_alias (query, keyword) VALUES ('account/order', 'order-history');
INSERT INTO url_alias (query, keyword) VALUES ('account/newsletter', 'newsletter');
INSERT INTO url_alias (query, keyword) VALUES ('product/special', 'specials');
INSERT INTO url_alias (query, keyword) VALUES ('affiliate/account', 'affiliates');
INSERT INTO url_alias (query, keyword) VALUES ('checkout/voucher', 'gift-vouchers');
INSERT INTO url_alias (query, keyword) VALUES ('product/manufacturer', 'brands');
INSERT INTO url_alias (query, keyword) VALUES ('information/contact', 'contact-us');
INSERT INTO url_alias (query, keyword) VALUES ('account/return/insert', 'request-return');
INSERT INTO url_alias (query, keyword) VALUES ('information/sitemap', 'sitemap');
INSERT INTO url_alias (query, keyword) VALUES ('account/forgotten', 'forgot-password');
INSERT INTO url_alias (query, keyword) VALUES ('account/download', 'downloads');
INSERT INTO url_alias (query, keyword) VALUES ('account/return', 'returns');
INSERT INTO url_alias (query, keyword) VALUES ('account/transaction', 'transactions');
INSERT INTO url_alias (query, keyword) VALUES ('account/register', 'create-account');
INSERT INTO url_alias (query, keyword) VALUES ('product/compare', 'compare-products');
INSERT INTO url_alias (query, keyword) VALUES ('product/search', 'search');
INSERT INTO url_alias (query, keyword) VALUES ('account/edit', 'edit-account');
INSERT INTO url_alias (query, keyword) VALUES ('account/password', 'change-password');
INSERT INTO url_alias (query, keyword) VALUES ('account/address', 'address-book');
INSERT INTO url_alias (query, keyword) VALUES ('account/reward', 'reward-points');
INSERT INTO url_alias (query, keyword) VALUES ('affiliate/edit', 'edit-affiliate-account');
INSERT INTO url_alias (query, keyword) VALUES ('affiliate/password', 'change-affiliate-password');
INSERT INTO url_alias (query, keyword) VALUES ('affiliate/payment', 'affiliate-payment-options');
INSERT INTO url_alias (query, keyword) VALUES ('affiliate/tracking', 'affiliate-tracking-code');
INSERT INTO url_alias (query, keyword) VALUES ('affiliate/transaction', 'affiliate-transactions');
INSERT INTO url_alias (query, keyword) VALUES ('affiliate/logout', 'affiliate-logout');
INSERT INTO url_alias (query, keyword) VALUES ('affiliate/forgotten', 'affiliate-forgot-password');
INSERT INTO url_alias (query, keyword) VALUES ('affiliate/register', 'create-affiliate-account');
INSERT INTO url_alias (query, keyword) VALUES ('affiliate/login', 'affiliate-login');
```

2. You need to modify the following `catalog/common/seo_url.php` file to look like the following:

```html
<?php
class ControllerCommonSeoUrl extends Controller {
 public function index() {
  // Add rewrite to url class
  if ($this->config->get('config_seo_url')) {
   $this->url->addRewrite($this);
  }

  // Decode URL
  if (isset($this->request->get['_route_'])) {
   $parts = explode('/', $this->request->get['_route_']);

   // remove any empty arrays from trailing
   if (utf8_strlen(end($parts)) == 0) {
    array_pop($parts);
   }

   foreach ($parts as $part) {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "url_alias WHERE keyword = '" . $this->db->escape($part) . "'");

    if ($query->num_rows) {
     $url = explode('=', $query->row['query']);

     if ($url[0] == 'product_id') {
      $this->request->get['product_id'] = $url[1];
     }

     if ($url[0] == 'category_id') {
      if (!isset($this->request->get['path'])) {
       $this->request->get['path'] = $url[1];
      } else {
       $this->request->get['path'] .= '_' . $url[1];
      }
     }

     if ($url[0] == 'manufacturer_id') {
      $this->request->get['manufacturer_id'] = $url[1];
     }

     if ($url[0] == 'information_id') {
      $this->request->get['information_id'] = $url[1];
     }

     if ($query->row['query'] && $url[0] != 'information_id' && $url[0] != 'manufacturer_id' && $url[0] != 'category_id' && $url[0] != 'product_id') {
      $this->request->get['route'] = $query->row['query'];
     }
    } else {
     $this->request->get['route'] = 'error/not_found';

     break;
    }
   }

   if (!isset($this->request->get['route'])) {
    if (isset($this->request->get['product_id'])) {
     $this->request->get['route'] = 'product/product';
    } elseif (isset($this->request->get['path'])) {
     $this->request->get['route'] = 'product/category';
    } elseif (isset($this->request->get['manufacturer_id'])) {
     $this->request->get['route'] = 'product/manufacturer/info';
    } elseif (isset($this->request->get['information_id'])) {
     $this->request->get['route'] = 'information/information';
    }
   }

   if (isset($this->request->get['route'])) {
    return new Action($this->request->get['route']);
   }
  }
 }

 public function rewrite($link) {
  $url_info = parse_url(str_replace('&amp;', '&', $link));

  $url = '';

  $data = array();

  parse_str($url_info['query'], $data);

  foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
   if (isset($data['route'])) {
    if (($data['route'] == 'product/product' && $key == 'product_id') || ( ($data['route'] == 'product/manufacturer/info' || $data['route'] == 'product/product') && $key == 'manufacturer_id') || ($data['route'] == 'information/information' && $key == 'information_id')) {
     $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "url_alias WHERE `query` = '" . $this->db->escape($key . '=' . (int)$value) . "'");

     if ($query->num_rows && $query->row['keyword']) {
      $url .= '/' . $query->row['keyword'];

      unset($data[$key]);
     }
    } elseif ($key == 'path') {
     $categories = explode('_', $value);

     foreach ($categories as $category) {
      $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "url_alias WHERE `query` = 'category_id=" . (int)$category . "'");

      if ($query->num_rows && $query->row['keyword']) {
       $url .= '/' . $query->row['keyword'];
      } else {
       $url = '';

       break;
      }
     }

     unset($data[$key]);
    } elseif ($key == 'route') {
                    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "url_alias WHERE `query` = '" . $value . "'");

                    if ($query->num_rows && ($query->row['keyword'] || $query->row['keyword'] == '')) {
                        $url .= '/' . $query->row['keyword'];

                        unset($data[$key]);
                    }
                }
   }
  }

  if ($url) {
   unset($data['route']);

   $query = '';

   if ($data) {
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
     $query .= '&' . rawurlencode((string)$key) . '=' . rawurlencode((string)$value);
    }

    if ($query) {
     $query = '?' . str_replace('&', '&amp;', trim($query, '&'));
    }
   }

   return $url_info['scheme'] . '://' . $url_info['host'] . (isset($url_info['port']) ? ':' . $url_info['port'] : '') . str_replace('/index.php', '', $url_info['path']) . $url . $query;
  } else {
   return $link;
  }
 }
}
```

This will rewrite all the links to whatever SEO keyword you assigned to that route on your url_alias table.

And that's it! Hopefully this helps more people, because it's a pain to dive in all that code.

Answer (score 0):

Where abouts on the front-end are the non-SEO friendly URL's (the ones with index.php?route= in them) appearing? If you've copied/pasted any into markup in your templates they will remain as they are. Opencart also has various redirects and things hard-coded into it's controller files which might redirect to such a URL. So it depends where these links are on your site.

Comment: Footer's link like account/order which should be /orders or main menu in header where I see links: account/login (should be /login), account/register (that I mean should be /register) etc.

Comment: What does the link look like in your footer.tpl template? It's supposed to grab the link from /catalog/controller/common/footer.php. This uses /system/library/url.php which is supposed to check your 'url_alias' table. It generates a URL with the index.php?route= part if no match is found, I believe.

Comment: You may look here http://ys.kz/shop/index.php?route=information/contact - this link is in footer, in url_alias I have information/contact=contact and link ys.kz/shop/contact - works, but question is why I still see in footer not shortened url ?   (PS: sorry site not in english)